# Software for remote access with on-screen auto-translation

Tags: software-development, remote-access, remote-desktop, translation, remote-control

I often have to connect remotely to foreign clients and sometimes language problems arise. Yes, you can use Google Translator, but it takes time to copy the text and translate it, and there isn't much time during a remote session. In addition, the text from the Windows system notifications cannot be copied. I have tried several ways, such as pointing the smartphone to the screen with the text and translating it via Google Lens or the Easy Screen OCR, but these are not very convenient. Can you recommend a service that does automatic translation while remotely connected?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Getscreen.me](https://getscreen.me) for this purpose. Just select the desired language on the panel, put the cursor on and the service shows online translation of the selected text. Recently I connected remotely to a client from China - the function was very useful. A pretty good alternative to Teamviewer or Anydesk, but cheaper.